# Unit Test (MSTest). C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mstest

Прошу помочь на начальных порах изучения модульных тестов. Пишу их первый раз.

Есть вот такой метод:

```
public static uint GCDByEuclid(uint num1, uint num2)
{
    while (num2 != 0)
    {
        uint temp = num2;
        num2 = num1 % num2;
        num1 = temp;
    }
    return num1;
}
```

для которого хочу написать модульный тест.
Создал проект тестов(MSTest) в MSVS 2019.
Написал там следующее:

```
[TestClass]
public class FindGCDTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GCDByEuclidTest()
    {
        (uint, uint) firstPair = (10, 50);
        uint expectedFirstPair = 10;
        (uint, uint) secondPair = (20, 21);
        uint expectedSecondPair = 1;
        (uint, uint) thirdPair = (1500, 3000);
        uint expectedThirdPair = 1500;
        (uint, uint) fourthPair = (22, 15);
        uint expectedfourthPair = 1;

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedFirstPair, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(firstPair.Item1, firstPair.Item2));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedSecondPair, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(secondPair.Item1, secondPair.Item2));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedThirdPair, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(thirdPair.Item1, thirdPair.Item2));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedfourthPair, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(fourthPair.Item1, fourthPair.Item2));
    }
}
```

Подскажите где что нужно убрать/добавить/поменять.

Comment: Да по сути всё верно, только кортеж вы используете как-то странно: он вам не помогает набивать новые кейсы, а наоборот - мешает.

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov можете поподробнее про кортеж?

Comment: ну смотрите. вы усложняете конструкцию теста применением (uint, uint). после этого вам приходится ещё и .Item1 / .Item2 писать, а что это даёт? ничего.

Применение кортежа или анонимного класса было бы оправдано, если бы он сосредотачивал в себе все необходимые данные для проведения одной операции Assert. Тогда вы могли бы избавиться от необходимости тестировать множество переменных, заменив это на цикл - проход по массиву кортежей.

Comment: Все - значит не два значения, а три.

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov то есть будет достаточно, если я буду использовать строковые константы(литералы) в Assert?

Comment: я такого не говорил! зачем вам строки-то понадобились, у вас везде (и в аргументах тестируемого метода, и в его возвращаемом значении - uint)

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov я имею в виду значения uint, которые сразу будут подставляться в Assert

Comment: Я оформил как ответ, потому что код в комментариях кажется не подсвечивается

Comment: тест кейсы лучше передавать в тест метод через параметры. Например используя InlineDataAttribute в xUnit или TestCaseAttribute в NUnit (не знаю есть ли аналог в MSTest).

Comment: @SultanovShamil, если нет конкретизации типа используемых модульных тестов. Есть ли какие-то предпочтительные варианты или это дело вкуса?

Comment: @TheKonstantin конкретный тип необязателен, можно передавать сколько угодно много аргументов через запятую, либо вынести атрибуты с тест кейсами в генераторы TestCaseSource, если требуются runtime возможности или тест кейсов стало много. Плюс в том, что так становится чище и проще поддерживать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы пишете несколько ассёртов в одном тесте, то при падении одного из них выполнение теста прервётся и вы не узнаете, сработают ли остальные. Это плохо, так как может понадобиться множество лишних прогонов тестов.

Использование цикла сути не меняет.

Специально для такого случая используются *параметризованные тесты*. В MSTest они [реализуются](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest#add-more-features) с помощью атрибутов `DataTestMethod` и [`DataRow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(10u, 50u, 10u)]
[DataRow(20u, 21u, 1u)]
[DataRow(1500u, 3000u, 1500u)]
[DataRow(22u, 15u, 1u)]
public void GCDByEuclidTest(uint num1, uint num2, uint expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(num1, num2));
}
```

В этом случае, если один из ассёртов упадёт, остальные выполнятся.

Есть и [другие](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2019) способы, но они более сложные и нужны, соответственно, для сложных случаев тестирования.

Документация MSTest страдает отсутствием примеров использования `DataSource` и `DynamicData`. Я нашёл лаконичные примеры [здесь](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/mstest-cheat-sheet/#tab-con-9). И, вероятно, стоит смотреть доки на гитхабе: [1](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/006-DynamicData-Attribute.md), [2](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/007-DataSource-Attribute-VS-ITestDataSource.md).

Comment: подскажите, а если мой метод имеет параметр _out TimeSpan time_, как его добавить в _DataRow_?

Comment: @TheKonstantin - `out` - это выходящий параметр. Поэтому в метод никакого значения передавать не надо. В `DataRow` только входящие значения задаются. А на место out-параметра передаётся переменная. Если что, задайте отдельный новый вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда можете объяснить, почему ваша реализация не проходит тесты? Метод, который тестируется, абсолютно корректно работает.

Comment: @TheKonstantin - я поправил код, добавил суффиксы `u` к числовым литералам. В таком виде код компилируется и тесты проходят.

Comment: @TheKonstantin - если у вас есть код, который нужно протестировать, с модификатором `out` у параметра, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: спасибо. Сейчас задам.

Answer (score 2):

Сам принцип тестирования вы усвоили правильно - нужно провести многократные испытания вашего метода. Единственная странность, на которую я пытался указать в комментариях - применение кортежа.

В вашем случае кортеж (или анонимный тип, который отличается от кортежа тем, что содержит содержит больше информации о членах) можно более эффективно использовать следующим образом:

```
// этот список содержит все тест кейсы
// первые два члена кортежа - аргументы, передаваемые в тестируемый метод
// третий член кортежа - известное возвращаемое значение, с которым сравнивается фактический результат

 List<(uint, uint, uint)> cases = new List<(uint, uint, uint)>()
        {
            (10, 50, 10),
            (20, 21, 1),
            (1500, 3000, 1500),
            (22, 15, 1)
        };

        foreach (var test in cases)
            Assert.AreEqual(test.Item3, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(test.Item1, test.Item2));
```

Comment: Не удается добавить в кортеж ни одну из пар, потому что нужно преобразовывать из int в uint.

Comment: нужно не _cases.Add(Tuple.Create(10, 50, 10));_, а просто _cases.Add((10, 50, 10));_ P.S.  _case_ - зарезервированное ключевое слово, нужно заменить его другим.

Comment: по поводу uint. Для этого типа существует литерал-суффикс `u`. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types