# Unit Tests (MS Test). Проблема в построении DataRow

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mstest

Есть метод с такой сигнатурой: `public static uint GCDByEuclid(uint num1, uint num2, out TimeSpan time)`

Для него нужно написать тест. В предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151540/unit-test-mstest-c) узнал, что это нужно делать через атрибут **DataRow**. Но теперь не понимаю как можно вставить, к примеру, **TimeSpan** в **DataRow**.

Моя попытка это сделать:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(10u, 50u, new TimeSpan(), 10u)]
[DataRow(20u, 21u, new TimeSpan(), 1u)]
[DataRow(1500u, 3000u, new TimeSpan(), 1500u)]
[DataRow(22u, 15u, new TimeSpan(), 1u)]
public void GCDByEuclidWithTimeTest(uint num1, uint num2, TimeSpan time, uint expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(num1, num2, out time));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тестовый метод в виде параметров должны передаваться только *входные* значения. А так как параметр с модификатором `out` *выходной*, то его следует убрать.
Получается следующее:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetDataForGCDByEuclidWithTimeTest), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void GCDByEuclidWithTimeTest(uint num1, uint num2, uint expected)
{
    TimeSpan time;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(num1, num2, out time));
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDataForGCDByEuclidWithTimeTest()
{
    yield return new object[] { 10u, 50u, 10u };
    yield return new object[] { 20u, 21u, 1u };
    yield return new object[] { 1500u, 3000u, 1500u };
    yield return new object[] { 22u, 15u, 1u };
}
```

И в зависимости от типа теста, может понадобиться проверять и параметр с `out`:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetDataForGCDByEuclidWithTimeTest), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void GCDByEuclidWithTimeTest(uint num1, uint num2, uint expected)
{
    TimeSpan time;
    uint actual = FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(num1, num2, out time);
    
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.IsTrue(time < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря более внимательному изучению [примеров](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/mstest-cheat-sheet/#tab-con-9), предложенных к ознакомлению *Alexander Petrov* в предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151540/unit-test-mstest-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), написал следующее:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetDataForGCDByEuclidWithTimeTest), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void GCDByEuclidWithTimeTest(uint num1, uint num2, TimeSpan time, uint expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, FindGCD.GCDByEuclid(num1, num2, out time));
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDataForGCDByEuclidWithTimeTest()
{
    yield return new object[] { 10u, 50u, new TimeSpan(), 10u };
    yield return new object[] { 20u, 21u, new TimeSpan(), 1u };
    yield return new object[] { 1500u, 3000u, new TimeSpan(), 1500u };
    yield return new object[] { 22u, 15u, new TimeSpan(), 1u };
}
```

Все отработало корректно. Правда не уверен на счет корректности тестирования таким образом(я никак не проверю *TimeSpan*, который, может, и не нужно првоерять).